# How to configure single unity container for multiple project's within an application?

Tags: unity-container

Since I am new to using Unity 2.0, I need some pointer or suggestion as to how can I configure a single Unity container for multiple project within the same application?

I need to configure the container using configuration files instead of the API.

Comment: Why do you need the container in multiple projects? Dependency injection recommends using the container in a single location called [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). Trying to use the container in several places is a code smell that indicates that you try to apply the [ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)

Comment: @SebastianWeber : I don't want to use container in multiple projects. What I want do is to create a single unity config file for each project and then use them to configure a single container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load different config files if you want to. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28PandP.20%29.aspx#_Loading_the_Configuration) describes how to load configuration from alternative files.